# How to Use Jquery Javascript Replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm using this in my wysiwyg to replace

```
< pre> Hi my name is< /pre>
```

with

```
< div id="precode">Hi my name is< /div>
```

This is the working code code

```
v=v.replace(/<pre>(.*)<\/pre>/gim,'<div id="precode">$1</div>');
```

This works fine unless the string contains a < br>

**EDIT**  This is the code

```
if(div){div.innerHTML=this.obj.toggletext||'Spell Check'}
$('#spellcheck_words').slideToggle('slow', function() { }); 
if(this.xhtml&&!this.ie){
v=v.replace(/<strong>(.*)<\/strong>/gi,'<span style="font-weight: bold;">$1</span>');               
v=v.replace(/(<img [^>]+[^\/])>/gi,'$1/>')
v=v.replace(/<em>(.*)<\/em>/gi,'<span style="font-weight: italic;">$1</span>')
}
```

**EDIT**

Comment: You're supposed to phrase your question as a... question

Comment: Sorry, I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or:

```
v=v.replace(/<pre>((?:.|[\r\n])*)<\/pre>/gim,'<div id="precode">$1</div>');
```

Problem is not with `<br/>`, but with new-line characters.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('pre').replaceWith('<div>'+$(this).html()+'</div>');
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
$('pre').replaceWith('<div>'+$(this).html()+'</div>');
```

so html gets passed over.